# Reverse Integer leetcode runtime

Tags: integer, runtime, reverse

i have solved this problem -> https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/description/(Reverse Integer leetcode ) by two ways

1)

this solution works perfectly

```
 class Solution {                      
public:
    int reverse(int x) {
        int r=0;      // decleare r 
        while(x){
         if (r>INT_MAX/10 || r<INT_MIN/10) return 0; // check 32 bit range if r is outside the range then return 0 
         r=r*10+x%10; // find remainder and add its to r
         x=x/10;     // Update the value of x
        } 
        return int(r);  // if r in the 32 bit range then return r
    }
};
```

2. but in this solution it is showing this message-> (runtime error: signed integer overflow: -846384741 * 10 cannot be represented in type 'int' (solution.cpp))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYoVj.png)

```
class Solution {
public:
    int reverse(int x) {
        
         bool neg =false;
        if(x<0){neg=true;x=abs(x);}
        

        int ans=0;
        int s= INT_MAX/10;
        while(x!=0){
            int a = x%10;
            x=x/10;
            if(ans>s){return 0;}
            ans = ans*10 +a;
            
        }
        cout<<s;

        if(neg)return -1*ans;
        return ans;
    }
};




in second  code i made x positive if it is negative and then do all the operations and finally i return answer according to the sign of initial x but why this code is showing error though it has exact same logic as first one can someone explain me what going wrong here ? ;
```